# Fold either to return different value

Tags: java, functional-programming, either, vavr

I have a Vavr Either that looks like this:

```
Either<DomainError, Boolean> maybePendingPayment = ...
```

I want to fold this response to return Either<DomainError, Optional>

```
return maybePendingPayment.fold(domainError -> domainError, pendingPayment ? GenericType.builder().build() : Optional.empty())
```

But it doesn't look like I can do this because fold wants me to return the same types:

```
[ERROR]     lower bounds: io.vavr.control.Either<xxx.yyy.DomainError,java.util.Optional<xxx.yyy.GenericType>>,java.lang.Object
[ERROR]     lower bounds: java.util.Optional<T>,java.util.Optional<T>,xxx.yyy.DomainError
```

Is there any way I can do this in a fancier way than just checking the left and right sides with an if-else?

Comment: A use case of `Either` is to encode computations that might yield an error. If you fold a value of this type you lose this abstraction and the need to handle errors pops up again. In order to make `fold` - the elimination rule of `Either` - type safe, both cases need to return a value of the same type. Usually a default value is used for the error case. If you don't have a meaningful default value, you should keep `Either` and instead lift functions into its context with functor, applicative and monad.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the explanation @scriptum!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying `fold` to your `Either` will (as the name already suggests) fold it and apply either the left or right function, returning the result of the applied function.

With the following example I tried to make more clear what is happening:

```
    public Optional<Object> verify() {
        Either<DomainError, Boolean> maybePendingPayment = Either.right(true);
        return maybePendingPayment.fold(Optional::of, pendingPayment -> pendingPayment ? Optional.of("pending payment") : Optional.empty());
    }
```

As you can see I chose `Optional<Object>` for the functions return type and wrapped the left function of the fold in an Optional as well. When unwrapping the `Either` your return type will either be the `Optional<DomainError>` or the result of the right function (in my example `String` or `Optional.empty`). If there is a common Supertype to what you are trying to return (between `GenericType` and `DomainError`), you could choose this one as a return type of the function instead of `Object`.